# How to encrypt and decrypt User data in joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, security, authentication

I am new to joomla, and working on joomla application which is currently running on production environment.

Application contains 1000+ registered users.

As per GDPR Policy, I have requirement for encryption and decryption of PII (User personal information) to prevent data loss.

In my application I am using user personal data for authentication purpose which contain name of user and email id, which needs to be encrypted before storing data in database and also needs to decrypt before using.

I am using core user authentication process of joomla

Application running on below versions
Joomla 3.9.7
Php 5.4.16
Apache 2.4.6
MySQL
Unix server

I know php5 is EOL now and needs to upgrade the same.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for your question. Please take our [tour] to familiarise yourself with this Stack Exchange community.

Comment: could you point us to the articles of GDPR that mandate it?  I remember that the encryption of data is strongly advised but not mandatory for data which isn't too sensitive i.e. emails. That said, in order to encrypt emails you might write a custom authentication plugin and implementing encryption there, and disable the basic one

Comment: Also, this should only be related to the requirement to inform users in case of a data breach. But your outdated stack may be more relevant in this respect

Comment: @RiccardoZorn So basically Encryption/decryption is not possible in joomla user core plugin.. and also I cannot write custom plugin as well because application is already contains 1000+ users